# Pointwise projection continuous?

Tags: continuity, hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and $U:=L^2(\Omega)$. Define $U^\prime = \{u\in U: a\leq u(x)\leq b \}$ for $a<b$. Let $P:U\rightarrow U^\prime$ be the "pointwise projection" of any $u\in U$ onto $U^\prime$, that is $P(u)(x)=u(x)$ if $u(x)\in [a,b]$ and $P(u)(x)=a$ if $u(x)<a$ and $P(u)(x)=b$ if $u(x)>b$ for all $x\in \Omega$.

How can I show that $P$ is a continuous operator? I know that the min and max of continuous functions are continuous and $P(u)(x)=\max\{a,\min\{u(x),b\}\}$, but $u$ need not be continuous.

Is the $P$ that I have defined simply a projection onto to convex set $U^\prime$, i.e. $P(u)=\arg\min\limits_{u^\prime \in U^\prime}||u-u^\prime||^2$? And then I somehow show that such projections are continuous? But how could I do that? Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P$ (as projection onto a non-empty, closed, convex set) is Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
$$
|P(u)-P(v)|\le |u-v|
$$
for all $u,v\in \mathbb R$.

Then by squaring and integrating that inequality we get for $u,v\in L^2(\Omega)$
$$
\|P(u)-P(v)\|_{L^2}^2 \le \|u-v\|_{L^2}^2.
$$